# Where to initializing instance with a View parameter in MVVM architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

I work on rewriting my app to MVVM architecture concept.
Based one my understanding all the business logic should live in the `ViewModel` and the UI components in the `Activity` or `Fragment`. I use a third party library that needs to be initialized with some view's like:  `MyLibrary instance = new MyLibrary ("key" , imageView, surfaceView)` and then doing some manipulations on these views.

What would be the best place and the right way doing that knowing that it's not recommended passing any Android view to the `ViewModel` and also not the right thing to initialize SDK in the `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

You have already answered your question. It's the other way around, the ViewModel informs the View (activities and fragment) WHAT should be chaged, and the View simply handles HOW it should be updated.

Most of the business logic however, if we want to be nitpcky, should still remain in the model. The ViewModel only holds the LiveData that the View needs. Some reasons for this is that you don't want your model to be Android architecture dependent. But also to follow the single purpose principle. This way you avoid making the ViewModel into a God object that handles everything. Instead you only allow it to format data, pass commands, provide factory methods for binding
to the viewModel, and subscribing/getting relevant changes from the model.

So in short: The View passes user-input to the ViewModel who issues commands on the Model. The ViewModel then format the changes from the Model and posts the changes using LiveData to the View. The View finally updates the components that the user can see.

Check the example here for how the UI is updated.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Read more about the pattern here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel

Comment: "should still remain in the model" ? I disagree with that. The model persist data, that's it,  and can be connected with a repository, but the model should not be responsible for the business logic.